# Elasticsearch query array of integers

Tags: elasticsearch

I have filed with values like

range:[50,60]

How do query this filed with value 55 and get all items which have 55 in between smallest and largest number in range array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html)

```
{
   "query": {
     "range": {
       "range": {
         "gte": 55
       }
     }
   }
}
```